# Why might I not be able to activate my drawing canvas grid guide?

Tags: interface

As you can see in my screenshot below -- my overlay "canvas Grid" is greyed out, despite being check-able. I'm new to Blender and still getting my bearings, so forgive the dumb question here! Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure why it's greyed out, but I don't think you will need it,  Is there some special reason you want it checked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like *Grid* is the grid that is displayed when you are both in orthographic AND perpendicular view, it allows you to view the units when in ortho front view, ortho right view, etc... it always displays a grid perpendicular to your view, whereas *Floor* is the floor, it's only an horizontal plane, and it is seen whatever is your view, orthographic or not, but it's still an horizontal plane.

In your case the option is grayed because you are not in orthographic AND perpendicular view. It will appear when you'll be in both.

[image]